Plotly renders complementary colors in Databricks dark mode
Example code:
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio

pio.templates.default = 'plotly_white'

x = np.random.rand(2000)
y = np.random.randn(2000)

trc = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers', marker_color='blue', marker_size=4)

fig.show(renderer='databricks')

Output image below (tested on plotly 5.9 and 5.18 in Databricks runtime environment 15.1).
I found out that the problem vanishes when I switch from dark to light mode in the settings. Also, when saving the file from the plot menu the colors are always correct, just the display in dark mode is inverted.
Any idea how to prevent this overzealous dark mode behavior?


I'm on plotly v5.18.0, running your code the marker color is properly set whatever the template. Also "specifying the theme as plotly_dark results in a white background plot", did you mean "plotly_white" or "black background" ? because it would be an issue otherwise..

I'm on Databricks runtime 15.1 which has plotly 5.9 as default. Just upgraded to 5.18, still the same issue. And regarding background: I really mean it as stated, the theme color is inverted. plotly_white => dark background (see image), plotly_dark => white background.

Ah ok, this is weird. Do you have other plotly figures using different templates in the same notebook ? I would try to output the figure in another way : fig = go.Figure(trc) then fig.show(renderer='azure') or fig.show(renderer='notebook').

In both cases I get ReferenceError: require is not defined as printed output, but no actual traceback. fig.show(renderer="databricks") works, but also with output in complementary colors.

Just edited the question... evil dark mode is the culprit.

Wow.. I think this happens because of the visualization feature which actually relies on Plotly: the notebook display seems to set its own dark/light template without even considering whether or not one is already set. They should set their theme as default and allow for customization instead of overriding. And the issue also occurs with matplotlib plots.

Before they fix that, you might want to try applying the whole template definition manually on the clientside using a post_script as for your previous question (ie. applying the template after the theme override occurs).
